# kioexec with multiple files

Tags: shell, kde

We have two environments here at work, and I access the remote machine over ssh. I can do this:

```
kioexec myeditor fish://me@remotemachine/path/to/file.txt
```

But I'd like to be able to do a diff between a local and remove file, something like

```
kioexec diff local_file.txt fish://me@remotemachine/path/to/file.txt
```

This doesn't seem like it works, do I need to update KDE? This is my work machine, and though I have root, I have limited flexibility in upgrades.

MACHINE: Linux CentOS 5.5, kde 3.5.4

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are using a non-KDE tool `diff` to compare the files. Try using a KDE program, like `kdiff3`, to do your job. KDE programs can handle other protocols using kioslaves.

Another possibility is a CLI KDE program which can display files. If you have such a program, you can chain other non-KDE programs:

```
cat_kde_cli fish://me@remotemachine/path/to/file.txt | diff local_file.txt -
```

Comment: But, my editor is not Kde, neither is cat (kioexec cat fish://yaddayadda works). It seems kioexec copies the file over to a temp file, runs the app as  a child proc, and uploads diff on any change on app exit. This should run for any app. Thanks much tho.

Comment: kdiff3 requires qt4/kde4, which is not on my system :( SOL as far as kdiff3 goes.

Comment: Have a look at the [changelog](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/ChangeLog). Maybe version 0.9.92 will work with KDE3 - the next version has KDE4 support.

Comment: Oh, and what's wrong with the `cat` approach? Isn't that what you were looking for? If not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: i was just trying to get it as a general case, for editing or using my diff tool (xxdiff). If i do the cat, kioexec will clean up and I wouldn't be able to do any edits. I really want kioexec to support multiple files, which it may do in KDE4.

Answer (score 1):

To update an old question....

The best I've done so far is to get around this problem a different way.

Namely [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) + [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) does what I want, and more.